# HTML using unknown font

Tags: html, fonts, embedding

I downloaded a font which I would like to use on a webpage. Of course this font isn't installed on the user's computer. How can I let a user's computer display that font? (I thought is was called: embedding a font but I could be wrong)
Thx for any help
VVW

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/@font-face).

A very easy way to generate the required cross-browser CSS and different formats of font file is to use:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

You simply upload your font and the generator does all the hard work.

Answer (score 2):

If the users have a relatively new/up-to-date browser:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: font-name
  src: url(path/to/font.ttf);
}

element {
  font-family: font-name;
}
```

> First, we add the @font-face declaration wherein we specify the path, filename, and font-family name for our custom font. Then we add the font choice in a CSS rule to our...element.<sup>1</sup>

Citation:

1. [A List Apart: Taking Advantage of HTML5 and CSS3 with Modernizr](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taking-advantage-of-html5-and-css3-with-modernizr/).

References:

- [@font-face, Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/@font-face)
- [CSS @ten, by Håkon Wium Lie](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssatten/)

Answer (score 0):

You are right that is called font-embedding. Here is what you need:
[Embedding fonts in CSS](http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol3/css_no15.htm)